# How to build a responsive thermometer panel using highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

Hey I am trying to build a thermometer panel using highcharts.
The way I build it: build several thermometers , a single thermometer(which is actual a column graph with a circle drawing in the end of the chart).

The thermometer is a factory service, I called the function generate chart of this service in order to generate a thermometer graph.

So far I have succeeded in the above task,but my component isn't responsive even in laptops or tablets.

I am using bootstrap and I am considering moving to flexbox instead, I need a guidance for where the responsive problem come from and how do I solved it.

**EDIT:**
**I think that the best way to handle this problem is unit the thermometer panel into one graph instead of 4 separated graphs, the question is: how can I do it?**

Here is my code:

a codepen of my code:http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/JRdRXv

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope","thermometer",function($scope,thermometer){
  $scope.title = "Hello World";
    var chartThermo1        = thermometer.generateChart("thermometer1","A00");
    var chartThermo2        = thermometer.generateChart("thermometer2","B03");
    var chartThermo3        = thermometer.generateChart("thermometer3","C04");
    var chartThermo4        = thermometer.generateChart("thermometer4", "TO");
                           
}])

app.factory('thermometer', function () {
        var thermometer = {};
        thermometer.generateChart = function (containerId,title) {
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    marginBottom: 50,
                    renderTo: containerId
                },
                series: [{
                    data: [70],
                    type: 'column',
                    pointWidth: 20,
                    threshold: -40,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    name: 'Temp'
                }],
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    tickWidth: 0
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 150,
                    minPadding: 0,
                    maxPadding: 0,
                    startOnTick: false,
                    endOnTick: false,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    tickInterval: 75,
                    minorTickInterval: 1,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                    tickWidth: 1,
                    minorTickWidth: 1
                },
                title: {
                    text: title
                }

            }, function (chart) {
                // Draw the shape
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    point = series.points[0],
                    radius = 20;
                chart.renderer.circle(
                    chart.plotLeft + point.shapeArgs.x + (point.shapeArgs.width / 2),
                    chart.plotTop + series.yAxis.len + radius - 5,
                    20
                )
                .attr({
                    fill: series.color
                })
                .add();
            });
            return chart;
        }
        return thermometer;

    });
```

```css
.thermometer{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 280px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.2.6/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl"> 
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
         <div id="thermometer1" class="thermometer flex-item"></div>
         <div id="thermometer2" class="thermometer flex-item"></div>
         <div id="thermometer3" class="thermometer flex-item"></div>
         <div id="thermometer4" class="thermometer flex-item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```